# How to integrate different project which are deployed in different servers...?

Tags: java, tomcat

My project are inter related and they are deployed in 5 different servers. If i want to run those project on one server or less than 5 servers.. because I want to reduce cost of server maintenance..? Then what should I have to DO??

Comment: Is there a programming-related question in this?

Answer (score 1):

Deploy all projects on one server with different project names.